# Why using LIMIT doesn't work anymore when downgrading from latest MySQL to MySQL 5.0.88?

Tags: mysql, limit

Not sure I'm in the correct here.

I have a stored procedure in MySQL, which limits results like so:

```
...
ORDER BY param_sort1, param_sort2
LIMIT param_start, param_end
;
```

Both *param_start* and *param_end* are passing in as integers like so:

```
...
IN `param_start` INT, 
IN `param_end` INT
...
```

While this is working on my developement server using the latest MySQL, the production server is still running MySQL 5.0.88 and throws a syntax error on the LIMIT clause. If I comment it out, it works correctly.

I'm fairly new to MySQL and completely clueless regarding how to do this correctly in older versions of MySQL.

**Question:**
Any tips how to get this working?

THANKS!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use variables or parameters for LIMIT arguments in MySQL 5.0. This feature was supported in MySQL 5.5.

As a workaround - construct a query string and execute it using [prepared statements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html).

---

something like this **(edited)**:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE procedure(IN param_start INT, IN param_end INT)
BEGIN
  SET @param_start = param_start;
  SET @param_end = param_end;
  SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT * FROM table LIMIT ?, ?');
  PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
  EXECUTE stmt USING @param_start, @param_end;
  DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END
```

Comment: I hate prepared statemets.... (and the manual...) let's see if I can get this to work.

Comment: Actually, it is easy to use prepared statemets. Have a look at the answer.

Comment: Is there a way to only set the two params as numbers and not run the whole query in the prep statement as the query itself is pretty large?

Comment: Yes, there is. From the doc: Within prepared statements, LIMIT parameters can be specified using ? placeholder markers. I will change my answer.

Comment: Hm. My actual query is using 25 parameters (param_start, param_end being the last two. So the only way to get this working is to feed all 25 params into the concat? Still not nice... I need to go. Will have a look later on and reply then

Answer (score 0):

This is a sample query which works with v5.1.36

*select * from `customer` limit 2000, 1000;*

I think you should upgrade to latest MySQL stable version and try as v5.0.88 is not stable anymore and MySQL has stopped supprting v5.0 tree,
Upgrade to v5.5 tree and see whether it has been fixed or not

These bug reports might be relavant
http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=50510
http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=46217